# See bookmark and URL at same time

Tags: firefox

In FF when I look at my bookmarks I see the bookmark name. I would like to be able to see the bookmark name and the URL at the same time.  I can see the URL in the tooltip when I hover over and I can see it when I pull up the edit bookmakrs planel but would like to see it properly when I just selecting bookmarks if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

Open the menu Boomarks, Show all Bookmarks, right-click on the header above the bookmarks, select Location. That should add the Location to the list on the right-hand side.